# Error when using Jekyll new command

Tags: jekyll

I use this command:

```
jekyll new blog
```

...and this error appeared:

```
WARNING: Could not read configuration. Using defaults (and options).
    No such file or directory - new/_config.yml
Building site: new -> blog
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:129:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /usr/local/bin/new/ (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:129:in `read_directories'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:101:in `read'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:39:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:264
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
```

I am using Ubuntu.

Ruby Gem Environment is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/wangxingyang/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

It seems like jekyll doesn't support new command.

How can I use its new command to init one project?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your $path variable is missing. Uninstalling and reinstalling jekyll should solve your problem.